# make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'something.o', needed by `something/built-in.o'. Stop

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I am very new in kernel coding and I am working on a school assignment. I am supposed to add a syscall to Kernel and compile it.
what I have did so far as following:
I have created a folder inside of kernel call it syscalls.

inside that syscall folder I have added 3 files :

1) syscall.c 2)syscall.h 3) makefile

the make file has only one line of code as following

```
obj-y := syscall.o
```

the syscall.c has a method the following signature:

```
asmlinkage long sys_call_function(struct array_stats *stats, long data[],long size)
```

Then I have added the following to arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl

```
330     common  syscall         sys_call_function
```

Then I have added the bold text bellow to kernel's Make file
core-y += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ **syscalls**/

Then I went **make clean** and then **make -j3**
But I get following error :

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `syscalls/syscall.o', needed by `syscalls/built-in.o'.  Stop.
```

make: *** [cs300] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

can any one please give me some hints. I am stuck and can't move ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Using this patch (against v4.0-rc7)

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 54430f9..874ac96 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -884,7 +884,7 @@ export mod_sign_cmd


 ifeq ($(KBUILD_EXTMOD),)
-core-y         += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/
+core-y         += kernel/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypto/ block/ xyz/

 vmlinux-dirs   := $(patsubst %/,%,$(filter %/, $(init-y) $(init-m) \
                     $(core-y) $(core-m) $(drivers-y) $(drivers-m) \
diff --git a/xyz/Makefile b/xyz/Makefile
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..0096b34
--- /dev/null
+++ b/xyz/Makefile
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+obj-y := abc.o
diff --git a/xyz/abc.c b/xyz/abc.c
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..1edff5b
--- /dev/null
+++ b/xyz/abc.c
@@ -0,0 +1,4 @@
+int somefunc(int somevar)
+{
+       return somevar + 2;
+}
```

I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you post your patch?